# How to specify single controller +single action for n routes in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, angular-routing

I have this initial configuration in my route.config.

- **routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ALBUMS",
                url: "albums/",
                defaults: new { controller = "Templates", action = "Connections", id= UrlParameter.Optional });**

[image]

Now how should I specify that anything after /albums/, like

1. /albums/bollywood
2. /albums/bollywood/hindi
3. /albums/tollywood
4. /albums/bollywood/hindi/old
5. /albums/bollywood/hindi/old/kishore

like this chain goes on. How to configure if url starts with /albums/ , please render 
**routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ALBUMS",
               url: "albums/",
               defaults: new { controller = "Templates", action = "Connections", id= UrlParameter.Optional });**

Because I don't have any bollywood,tollywood actions.
In actual, I have Welcome controller and action Selected.. thats it.
All others are templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Album",
                url: "Album/{*anything}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Album",action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

(if you also have the default route, this should go before it)

Comment: Yes, You are right. but I made sure the `/{*anything}` matches the `defaults:new {controller = "Album" , action ="Index", antyhing =UrlParamter.Optional }`